# выполнение кода на вебстранице на django

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Есть сайт на django, запускается с помощью nginx + gunicorn, на странице есть 4 frameset в которых должно происходить выполнение кода python и отображение его принтами из кода на страницу, но я столкнулся с тем что при запуске сервера - я вижу отображение frameset и код который должен выполнятся - просто текстом выводится в frameset
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я в теории узнал что это как-то нужно править в nginx или gunicorn но не нашел (или не понял) решения в интернете

```html
index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows=100% >
        <frameset rows=76%,24% >
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=reports src="{% url 'core:reports-name' %}">
                <frame name=fg_log src= >
            </frameset>
            <frameset cols=64%,36% >
                <frame name=fp_log src= >
                <frame name=ls src= >
            </frameset>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

```
**urls.py**
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('reports', views.reports, name='reports-name')
]

**views.py**
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render


User = get_user_model()


#@login_required
def index(request):
    template = 'core/index.html'
    return render(request, template)


def login(request):
    pass

#@login_required
def reports(request):
    template = 'cgi/reports.py'
    return render(request, template)
```